# Change message colors in message in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, display-settings

Is there a way to change the background color of the validation message for the inputs in  Chrome (under win)?

For example, can I change this to white?

Edit: This is a shot from internal validation in Chrome under windows. No JavaScript involved here. Here is the code:

```
<form>
    <input type="date" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: Does that happen for *all* validation online? As surfasb said, this is something the HTML/CSS/JavaScript of a website controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is controlled by the webpage itself. Web controls aren't Win32 controls.